# What adjective to describe this moral idea is "better, higher" than that idea?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, phrase-requests

In the story I am writing, a villain says that his "moral solution/idea" is "better, grander, more shining, more moral" than anything in the world.

What word or phrase could I use to describe that quality?

Comment: Perhaps "narcissistic grandiosity"? I'm not trying to be funny, it just seems odd to me that the villain is claiming higher moral ground without adding something to make it clear he is doing so only in his own mind.

Comment: Actually, by destroying the world, he claims that he is making way for a new species better than the "filthy humans". In his mind, humans' existence is blocking the chain of natural evolution :)

Comment: I just could NOT resist: http://www.eviloverlord.com/lists/overlord.html

Comment: ahhhhhhhh...what?

Answer (score 1):

Not coming up with any one-word adjectives, but as a noun, what about '[pinnacle](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pinnacle)'?

Comment: I have been using "pinnacle" quite lot in this chapter. I'm looking for a different words. But thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

How about the word ***[grand](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/grand)***?

It has many meaning, so for instance:

> An endeavor with a *grand* mission. (i.e. Having a serious moral purpose; noble)

or,

> Corruption on a grand scale. (i.e. Large and impressive in size or extent)